# Load layer from SharePoint (or online office server) with https://... URL

Tags: qgis, windows, file-path, sharepoint

I'm trying to import a .csv layer from a SharePoint folder without using the local path (for ex: C:**Users**\UserName\Folder1\filename) but using the online path (https://.../filename).
I need this because I want to have a unique path that leads to the file and I don't want the other colleagues to reload the path.
Is there a way to do it?

I'm using QGIS 3.28.3.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

I thought this should be possible using the `Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Layer` menu option and using the Source Type `Protocol: HTTP(S)…` option.

My URL was like:

`https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/mysite/path/to/io.csv?d=wd5429e9d377d45a8ae7e97d28cb3d9c8&csf=1&web=1&e=meESDW`

But it fails!

The issue for me is with the handling of the required authentication, with QGIS only supporting BASIC authentication and my SharePoint instance not supporting it.

If your SharePoint service supports BASIC authentication then it may work, otherwise you may need to come up with another solution, perhaps proxy through IIS.